# Couldn't run my JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I finished my program and now i am trying to create a jar file to run it from, but when i try to do so, nothing happens, no error, not execution, no nothing.This is the path: **D:\Eclipse\workspace\Game\src\AppPackage** I compiled my class **D:\Eclipse\workspace\Game\src\AppPackage javac Game.java** Created my manifest and jar file : **echo Main-Class: Game >manifest.txt** and
**jar cvfm Game.jar manifest.txt *.class**

This is how i add a image from the *images* folder :

```
field.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/8.png"));
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run it with `java -jar Game.jar` from the command line?

Comment: Why don't you use Eclipse to create the jar?

Comment: Manifest files have a ".mf" mime type. Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html).

Comment: @JonSkeet It gives me an error : **Error: Could not find or load main class Game**

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the fact that my program is actually a GUI and that i have a separate folder( next to "src" folder) called _images_ where i have my images ?

Comment: Well that might be *part* of the problem. We can't tell, really. Have you looked inside your jar file to see what's there? Is your class in a package at all?

Comment: How do i look inside of it ? Well.. i think it is : This is the hierarchy  : http://imgur.com/yDydahZ

Comment: You need to specify the package for the Main-Class as well: `AppPackage.Game`.

Comment: @AndreiVajnaII I have tried it and it tells me **Error: Could not find or load main class AppPackage.Game**

Comment: How do i add the _images_ folder as well in the JAR file ? Take a look at my edit on how i add the images in my program.

Comment: Try running the command from the src folder, not the AppPackage folder.

Answer (score 0):

You try to load the class Game from default package. But the path says you have the class in the AppPackage package. So Class should be AppPackage.Game
Also: you should use the IDE function to make the jar since only then the data gets packed together correctly. Afaik every IDE got a feature for that

Comment: Tried this tutorial : https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm , But i get this error : **Error:Invalid or corrupt jarfile C:\_path_\Game.jar**

Comment: Basically it worked, but i had to modify my code and copy all images from the _images_ folder in the same folder where the _src_ is . How can i keep  my images in the _images_ folder ?

Comment: Usually IDEs also allow to define resource folders. Define the images folder as one and the IDE copies the images folder in the jar automatically

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial: [Creating a JAR File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html).

For your case, first of all you have to run the jar command from the src folder. For the `Main-Class` you have to specify the fully qualified name of the class, that means including the package: `AppPackage.Game`.

To include any other folder you just write it in the command line, like this:

`jar cvfm Game.jar manifest.txt *.class images`

You can get more details in the link.